# Combining texture memory Unified Memory in CUDA 6

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, nvidia, tegra

I am writing a CUDA application for Jetson TK1 using CUDA 6. I have got the impression from Mark Harris in his blog post

[Jetson TK1: Mobile Embedded Supercomputer Takes CUDA Everywhere](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/jetson-tk1-mobile-embedded-supercomputer-cuda-everywhere/)

that the memory of the Tegra K1 is physically unified. I have also observed results indicating that `cudaMallocManaged` is significantly faster for global memory than ordinary `cudaMemcpy`. This is probably because the Unified Memory doesn't require any copying.

However, what do I do when I want to use the texture memory for parts of my application? I have not found any support for textures using `cudaMallocManaged` so I have assumed that I have to use normal `cudaMemcpyToArray` and `bindTextureToArray`?

Using the previous mentioned method often seem to work but the variables managed by `cudaMallocManaged` sometimes give weird segmentation faults for me. Is this the right way to use texture memory along with Unified Memory? The following code illustrates how I do it. This code works fine but my question is whether this is the right way to go or if it might create undefined behaviour that could cause e.g. segmentation faults.

```
#define width 16
#define height 16
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> input_tex;

__global__ void some_tex_kernel(float* output){
    int i= threadIdx.x;
    float x = i%width+0.5f;
    float y =  i/width+0.5f;
    output[i] = tex2D(input_tex, x, y);
}

int main(){
    float* out;
    if(cudaMallocManaged(&out, width*height*sizeof(float))!= cudaSuccess)
        std::cout << "unified not working\n";

    for(int i=0; i< width*height; ++i){
        out[i] = float(i);
    }

    const cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
    cudaArray* input_t;
    cudaMallocArray(&input_t, &desc, width, height);
    cudaMemcpyToArrayAsync(input_t, 0, 0, out, width*height*sizeof(float),  cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    input_tex.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    cudaBindTextureToArray(input_tex, input_t, desc);

    some_tex_kernel<<<1, width*height>>>(out);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(int i=0;i<width*height; ++i)
        std::cout << out[i] << " ";

    cudaFree(out);
    cudaFreeArray(input_t); 
    }
}
```

Another thing that I find odd is that if I remove the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in the code I always get segmentation faults. I understand that the result might not be finished if I read it without a synchronization but should not the variable still be accessible?

Anyone have a clue?

Mattias

Comment: I might be wrong but texture memory needs to be available to the device and cached in a particular way, I can't find anything that states that the managed memory pool can be used to do that so you shouldn't assume it.

Comment: Please, post the minimum sized code that someone else could copy, paste, compile and run to diagnose your problem with segmentation faults.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @MarcoA. I think it gave me a better understanding of unified memory.

Comment: @JackOLantern I posted some sample code of what I am trying to do. The code works fine but my question is more if the general method is correct. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [only managed memory possibilities at this time](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-opt-in) are static allocations using `__device__ __managed__` or dynamic allocations using `cudaMallocManaged()`.  There is no direct support for textures, surfaces, constant memory, etc.

Your usage of texturing is fine.  The only overlap between texture usage and managed memory is in the following call:

```
cudaMemcpyToArrayAsync(input_t, 0, 0, out, width*height*sizeof(float),  cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

where managed memory is the source (i.e. host side) of the transfer.  This is acceptable as long as the call is issued during a period when no kernels are executing (see below).

> "Another thing that I find odd is that if I remove the cudaDeviceSynchronize() in the code I always get segmentation faults."

`cudaDeviceSynchronize();` is necessary after a kernel call to make the managed memory visible to the host again.  I suggest you read [this section of the documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#um-coherency-hd) carefully:

> "In general, it is not permitted for the CPU to access any managed allocations or variables while the GPU is active. Concurrent CPU/GPU accesses, ... will cause a segmentation fault..."

As you've indicated, the code you posted works fine.  If you have other code that has unpredictable seg faults while using managed memory, I would carefully inspect the code flow (especially if you are using streams i.e. concurrency) to make sure that the host is accessing managed data only after a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` has been issued, and before any subsequent kernel calls.

Comment: Thanks for the help and for specifying where to read! I guess it makes sense that concurrent accesses cause segmentation faults.

Answer (score 3):

Robert Crovella has already answered to your question. However, in order to show you that `cudaMallocManaged` can be used in the framework of texture memory, I have dusted my 1D linear interpolation code and converted it using `cudaMallocManaged`. You will see that the code performs the 1D linear interpolation in four different ways:

- CPU;
- GPU;
- GPU using `tex1Dfetch`;
- GPU using `tex1D` filtering.

The code works without problems in all the cases and, especially, the latter two ones, on a Kepler K20c card.

```
// includes, system
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

// includes, cuda 
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

using namespace std;

texture<float, 1, cudaReadModeElementType> data_d_texture_filtering;
texture<float, 1> data_d_texture;

#define BLOCK_SIZE 256

/******************/
/* ERROR CHECKING */
/******************/
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) { getch(); exit(code); }
    }
}

/************/
/* LINSPACE */
/************/
// --- Generates N equally spaced, increasing points between a and b and stores them in x 
void linspace(float* x, float a, float b, int N) {
    float delta_x=(b-a)/(float)N;
    x[0]=a;
    for(int k=1;k<N;k++) x[k]=x[k-1]+delta_x;
}

/*************/
/* RANDSPACE */
/*************/
// --- Generates N randomly spaced, increasing points between a and b and stores them in x 
void randspace(float* x, float a, float b, int N) {
    float delta_x=(b-a)/(float)N;
    x[0]=a;
    for(int k=1;k<N;k++) x[k]=x[k-1]+delta_x+(((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX-0.5)*(1./(float)N));
}

/******************/
/* DATA GENERATOR */
/******************/
// --- Generates N complex random data points, with real and imaginary parts ranging in (0.f,1.f)
void Data_Generator(float* data, int N) {
    for(int k=0;k<N;k++) {
        data[k]=(float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
    }
}

/*************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION KERNEL - CPU */
/*************************************/
float linear_kernel_CPU(float in)
{
    float d_y;
    return 1.-abs(in);
}

/***************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION FUNCTION - CPU */
/***************************************/
void linear_interpolation_function_CPU(float* result_GPU, float* data, float* x_in, float* x_out, int M, int N){

    float a;
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++){
        int k = floor(x_out[j]+M/2);
        a = x_out[j]+M/2-floor(x_out[j]+M/2);
        result_GPU[j] = a * data[k+1] + (-data[k] * a + data[k]);
    }   
}

/*************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION KERNEL - GPU */
/*************************************/
__device__ float linear_kernel_GPU(float in)
{
    float d_y;
    return 1.-abs(in);
}

/**************************************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION KERNEL FUNCTION - GPU - GLOBAL MEMORY */
/**************************************************************/
__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU(float* __restrict__ result_d, const float* __restrict__ data_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if(j<N)
    {
        float reg_x_out = x_out_d[j]+M/2;
        int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out); 
        float a = reg_x_out - truncf(reg_x_out);
        float dk = data_d[k];
        float dkp1 = data_d[k+1];
        result_d[j] = a * dkp1 + (-dk * a + dk);
    } 
}

/***************************************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION KERNEL FUNCTION - GPU - TEXTURE MEMORY */
/***************************************************************/
__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_texture(float* __restrict__ result_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    if(j<N)
    {
        float reg_x_out = x_out_d[j]+M/2;
        int k = __float2int_rz(reg_x_out); 
        float a = reg_x_out - truncf(reg_x_out);
        float dk = tex1Dfetch(data_d_texture,k);
        float dkp1 = tex1Dfetch(data_d_texture,k+1);
        result_d[j] = a * dkp1 + (-dk * a + dk);
    } 
}

/************************************************************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION KERNEL FUNCTION - GPU - TEXTURE MEMORY - FILTERING FEATURES */
/************************************************************************************/
__global__ void linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_texture_filtering(float* __restrict__ result_d, const float* __restrict__ x_out_d, const int M, const int N)
{
    int j = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x; 
    if(j<N) result_d[j] = tex1D(data_d_texture_filtering,float(x_out_d[j]+M/2+0.5));
}

/***************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION FUNCTION - GPU */
/***************************************/
void linear_interpolation_function_GPU(float* result_d, float* data_d, float* x_in_d, float* x_out_d, int M, int N){

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,1); dim3 dimGrid(N/BLOCK_SIZE + (N%BLOCK_SIZE == 0 ? 0:1),1);
    linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(result_d, data_d, x_out_d, M, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

/********************************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION FUNCTION - GPU - TEXTURE MEMORY */
/********************************************************/
void linear_interpolation_function_GPU_texture(float* result_d, float* data_d, float* x_in_d, float* x_out_d, int M, int N){

    cudaBindTexture(NULL, data_d_texture, data_d, M*sizeof(float));

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,1); dim3 dimGrid(N/BLOCK_SIZE + (N%BLOCK_SIZE == 0 ? 0:1),1);
    linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_texture<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(result_d, x_out_d, M, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
}

/*****************************************************************************/
/* LINEAR INTERPOLATION FUNCTION - GPU - TEXTURE MEMORY - FILTERING FEATURES */
/*****************************************************************************/
void linear_interpolation_function_GPU_texture_filtering(float* result_d, float* data, float* x_in_d, float* x_out_d, int M, int N){

    cudaArray* data_d = NULL; gpuErrchk(cudaMallocArray(&data_d, &data_d_texture_filtering.channelDesc, M, 1)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpyToArray(data_d, 0, 0, data, sizeof(float)*M, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice)); 
    gpuErrchk(cudaBindTextureToArray(data_d_texture_filtering, data_d)); 
    data_d_texture_filtering.normalized = false; 
    data_d_texture_filtering.filterMode = cudaFilterModeLinear;

    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,1); dim3 dimGrid(N/BLOCK_SIZE + (N%BLOCK_SIZE == 0 ? 0:1),1);
    linear_interpolation_kernel_function_GPU_texture_filtering<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(result_d, x_out_d, M, N);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{

    int M=1024;             // --- Number of input points

    int N=1024;             // --- Number of output points

    int Nit = 100;          // --- Number of computations for time measurement

    // --- Input sampling
    float* x_in; gpuErrchk(cudaMallocManaged(&x_in,sizeof(float)*M));

    // --- Input data
    float *data;        gpuErrchk(cudaMallocManaged(&data,(M+1)*sizeof(float))); Data_Generator(data,M); data[M]=0.;

    // --- Output sampling
    float* x_out;       gpuErrchk(cudaMallocManaged((void**)&x_out,sizeof(float)*N)); randspace(x_out,-M/2.,M/2.,N);

    // --- Result allocation
    float *result_CPU;                          result_CPU=(float*)malloc(N*sizeof(float));
    float *result_d;                            gpuErrchk(cudaMallocManaged(&result_d,sizeof(float)*N));
    float *result_d_texture;                    gpuErrchk(cudaMallocManaged(&result_d_texture,sizeof(float)*N));
    float *result_d_texture_filtering;          gpuErrchk(cudaMallocManaged(&result_d_texture_filtering,sizeof(float)*N));

    // --- Reference interpolation result as evaluated on the CPU
    linear_interpolation_function_CPU(result_CPU, data, x_in, x_out, M, N);

    float time;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int k=0; k<Nit; k++) linear_interpolation_function_GPU(result_d, data, x_in, x_out, M, N);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    cout << "GPU Global memory [ms]: " << setprecision (10) << time/Nit << endl;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int k=0; k<Nit; k++) linear_interpolation_function_GPU_texture_filtering(result_d_texture_filtering, data, x_in, x_out, M, N);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    cout << "GPU Texture filtering [ms]: " << setprecision (10) << time/Nit << endl;

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);
    for (int k=0; k<Nit; k++) linear_interpolation_function_GPU_texture(result_d_texture, data, x_in, x_out, M, N);
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);
    cout << "GPU Texture [ms]: " << setprecision (10) << time/Nit << endl;

    float diff_norm=0.f, norm=0.f;
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        diff_norm = diff_norm + (result_CPU[j]-result_d[j])*(result_CPU[j]-result_d[j]);
        norm      = norm      + result_CPU[j]*result_CPU[j];
    }
    printf("Error GPU [percentage] = %f\n",100.*sqrt(diff_norm/norm));

    float diff_norm_texture_filtering=0.f;
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        diff_norm_texture_filtering = diff_norm_texture_filtering + (result_CPU[j]-result_d_texture_filtering[j])*(result_CPU[j]-result_d_texture_filtering[j]);
    }
    printf("Error texture filtering [percentage] = %f\n",100.*sqrt(diff_norm_texture_filtering/norm));

    float diff_norm_texture=0.f;
    for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
        diff_norm_texture = diff_norm_texture + (result_CPU[j]-result_d_texture[j])*(result_CPU[j]-result_d_texture[j]);
    }
    printf("Error texture [percentage] = %f\n",100.*sqrt(diff_norm_texture/norm));

    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an example!